# how to add trailing slash to specific rewrite rule? htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

how to add trailing slash to this rewrite rule if page loaded without trailing slash?

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```